# Incompatible types in assignment error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been working on this tutorial at Apple's documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/06Controller/06Controller.html

However, when I try to run and build the code, I get an incompatible types in assignment error.

```
#import "ConverterController.h"

@implementation ConverterController
- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender {
    float amount;
    converter = [[Converter alloc]init]; 
    [converter setSourceCurrencyAmount:[dollarField floatValue]]; 
    [converter setRate:[rateField floatValue]]; 
    amount =   [converter convertCurrency]; 
    [amountField setFloatValue:amount]; 
    [rateField selectText:self]; 
}
@end
```

The error is on the line of code which reads:
amount = [converter convertCurrency];

I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Can you help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `convertCurrency` doesn't return a float, which is the type for `amount`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. Can you show how the float would be incorporated into the code?

Comment: What type does the `convertCurrency` method in the Converter class return?

Comment: It returns a float: #import "Converter.h"


@implementation Converter

@synthesize sourceCurrencyAmount, rate;

- (float)convertCurrency {
    return self.sourceCurrencyAmount * self.rate;
}

@end
Not sure about where I should put float in the code mentioned above. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Did you complete the previous parts of this tutorial? In part 4, Defining the Model, you are asked to create a separate file for Converter objects:

```
#import "Converter.h"

@implementation Converter

@synthesize sourceCurrencyAmount, rate;

- (float)convertCurrency {

    return self.sourceCurrencyAmount * self.rate;

}

@end
```

This ought to allow Converter objects to recognize that they have a function called convertCurrency that returns a float.